Functionality of getVoteAccounts without relying on the RPC call
As the title indicates, i'm trying to get the functionality of the getVoteAccounts without relying on the rpc call.
So this method results in 2 arrays: one containing current validatores and another for delinquent ones, along with associated params such as nodePubkey and activatedStake
My goal is to get this data in an on-chain context to validate the signer of an ix with this nodePubkey, validate  activatedStake etc
Thank you in advance.

In my opinion, you cannot fully replicate getVoteAccounts on-chain because Solana programs (smart contracts) cannot directly access or query global account data (like all vote accounts) or perform the complex aggregation and filtering logic provided by the RPC node, due to the constrained runtime environment and lack of global data access in on-chain execution.
